# Deleting the records in ms access database

Tags: c#

I have used  this code to delete records From MS Access Database table. The program is running successfully, but records in the database are not being Deleted.

```
private void button3_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        String query=" delete from [student table] where Name="+txtname.Text+"";
        command.CommandText= query;
       MessageBox .Show ("Data deleted");
        connection.Close();

    }
```

Comment: 1) You're never executing the command. 2) And you want to guard against SQL injection attacks by never appending user supplied inputs directly to a query statement.

Comment: I had something in there about using "delete * from..." in Access, but I can't recall if that's optional or required, and I wouldn't know if it has been altered in recent versions of Access anyway, so I removed it, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Add `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` before you show the messagebox.

Comment: you have to execute the query like others suggested but I was going to suggest changing the Name="" to a like statement. imo if the user is providing the search string you have to make a more generous match. you also don't have the * in the delete from statement. also access data tables are accessed (for dbo schema) like dbo_Students instead of just typing in Students as the table name. That's how I delete records in vba macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
using (var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString))
using (var myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    var nameParam = new OleDbParameter("@name", txtname.Text);

    myCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM [student table] WHERE (Name) = @name";
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```